# How can I save an image generated from a php script into an actual .png image?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

How can I save a php-built-png image as a png file on my server?

For example let's say my script image-builder-png.php generates a blank box png image with the parameters passed to it:

```
/image-builder-png.php?color=orange&width=100&height=100
```

If I were simply citing this image in HTML this would render fine:

```
<img src="/image-builder-png.php?color=orange&width=100&height=100">
```

But I need to pass this image to another server script that only accepts standard image files like `orange-box.png`.

So how can I "save" the rendered image from `/image-builder-png.php?color=orange&width=100&height=100` as `orange-box.png`.

Comment: With `copy("http://.../imgbuild", "file.png");` for instance. Or editing your image builder script to use `imagepng()` with a filename.

Answer (score 0):

If serving on Apache, just use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to mask the PHP script parameters into a full path, and alter your script to figure out the dynamic parts.

```conf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/image-builder/(.*)$ /image-builder-png.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now an example request of "`/image-bulder/100x100/orange-box.png`" will be mapped to "`/image-builder-png.php?path=100x100/orange-box.png`". A simple preamble at the top of your PHP script should be able to extract the information, and correct the dynamic options. Something like ...

```php
if(isset($_GET['path']))
{
   $parts = explode('/',$_GET['path']);
   foreach($parts as $part)
   {
     if(preg_match('!^(?<width>\d+)x(?<height>\d+)$!',$part,$matches))
     {
       $_GET['width'] = $matches['width'];
       $_GET['height'] = $matches['height'];
     }
     if(preg_match('!^(?<color>\w+)-box\.png$!',$part,$matches))
     {
       $_GET['color'] = $matches['color'];
     }
   }
}
```